# TFS 2015 - failed to create the (analysis) excel report

Tags: tfs

When I tried to create a TFS excel report (analysis) I failed to login with my user.
When creating (simple) excel query table the login is succeeding. 
I followed the instructions from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/report/admin/grant-permissions-to-reports).

How can I investigate this problem?

Thanks,

---

Thanks,

Comment: Creating report: right click on query -> 'Create report in Microsoft Excel'

Comment: Are you able to access the Analysis Cube from Excel?

Comment: I can access the cube. but, when I tried to create report, I failed to login.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate these reports only when you work with an on-premises TFS that has been configured with reporting services. Requirements for creating Excel reports from a work item query:

1. Your deployment needs to be integrated with reporting services.
2. You must be a member of the **TfsWarehouseDataReader** security roles. T
3. A version of Excel that is compatible with Office 2007, Office 2010, or Office 2013.
4. Either Visual Studio or the Team Explorer plug-in for Visual Studio

You need to install Team Explorer to get the Team Foundation add-in for Excel.

Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports

Comment: Try to clean the user cache: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache. If issue persists, share a error screenshot.

Comment: can I delete all the folder in the cache folder? I don't have any errors, just failed to login. How can it be that I can create regular excel tfs report and not the analytic one.

Comment: Yes, you can delete all content in the cache folder. Also, go to Excel--Data--From Other Sources--From Analysis Services, to see whether you can connect it with the log on credentials.

Comment: I did it and again I failed to login.

Comment: Did you log on with Windows Authentication or use User Name+Password? Any error message this time? Try the items below to check the result: 1. log on with another credential, 2. log on on another client machine.